# go routines and a channel to receive error or success

Tags: go

I have a function that I want to define a maximum number of go routines, I have a list and I go through this list and I send a message to the go routines through the channel, and in this go routine I will call a function that will either get an answer or an err, when it's not an err I want to save the return in a slice, and when it's an err I want to stop the go routines and make a call.
but I'm not able to make it so that when I have an error, all the go routines end, and I need the value of err

```
type response struct {
    value string
}

func Testing() []response {

    fakeValues := getFakeValues()

    maxParallel := 25
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(maxParallel)

    if len(fakeValues) < maxParallel {
        maxParallel = len(fakeValues)
    }

    errReceive := make(chan error, 1)
    defer close(errReceive)

    response := make([]response, 0)
    valuesChan := make(chan string, 1)

    for i := 0; i < maxParallel; i++ {
        go func(valuesChan <-chan string, errReceive chan error) {
            for value := range valuesChan {
                resp, err := getFakeResult(value)
                if err != nil {
                    errReceive <- err
                }

                response = append(response, resp)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(valuesChan, errReceive)
    }

    for _, val := range fakeValues {
        valuesChan <- val
    }

    close(valuesChan)
    wg.Wait()

    err := <-errReceive
    if err != nil {
        // make any thing
    }

    return response
}

func getFakeValues() []string {
    return []string{"a", "b"}
}

func getFakeResult(val string) (response, error) {
    if val == "a" {
        return response{}, fmt.Errorf("ooh noh:%s", val)
    }

    return response{
        value: val,
    }, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a context with cancel and use it to let the go routines know they should stop.

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
defer cancel()

wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(1)
go func(ctx context.Context) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("context is done")
            return
        case <-time.After(time.Second):
            fmt.Println("work")
        }
    }
}(ctx)

time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
cancel()
wg.Wait()
```

https://go.dev/play/p/qe2oDppSnaF

---

Here is an example that showcases it better in the context of your use case.

```
type result struct {
    err error
    val int
}
```

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
defer cancel()

rchan := make(chan result, 5)
wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println("context is done")
                return
            case <-time.After(time.Second):
                n := rand.Intn(100)
                if n > 90 {
                    rchan <- result{err: fmt.Errorf("error %d", n)}
                } else {
                    rchan <- result{val: n}
                }
            }
        }
    }(ctx)
}

go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(rchan)
}()

for res := range rchan {
    if res.err != nil {
        fmt.Println(res.err)
        cancel()
        break
    } else {
        fmt.Println(res.val)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Z63n1h2A81o

Comment: but how would I be able to stop only when it is an error case like I put in the example above?

Comment: @Ming, you call `cancel` when you receive an error on `errReceive`.

Comment: could you ask me one more question? I have the function return: getFakeResult, a response, err
I believe that initializing a slice of []response outside the go routine and appending it with the response of the go routine is correct?

or should I have channel to pass the message from the go routine to the channel and then I use append?

Comment: @Ming, sorry I dont understand your question.